# AZURE IOT hub state is showing suspended in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

state of the AZURE IOT hub state is showing suspended in Azure portal. how can i make it active. I didn't get how to activate it any solutions.

Comment: Have you go over the maximum number of messages that your IoT Hub service tier is allowing?

Comment: Has your subscription no credit remaining?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT does the subscription even need any credit to continue? MSDN site clearly states it's a free service.

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT hub can be suspended due to a spending limit. You may try to follow these steps to check yours and active it:

1. Click your account in the upper right corner of Azure Portal and view your bill like this:

[image]

2. Then in the new webpage, select "ACCOUNT CENTER" like this:

[image]

3. You will see the reason of suspending, here for my case, I need to select "remove the spending limit", and then pay for my account.

[image]